# Compare static time in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to make a complex query to know if a store is open in a certain time of the day. This is a partial query.

```
current_time = %Time{(time_now |> DateTime.to_time()) | microsecond: {0, 0}}
current_time_string = time_now |> DateTime.to_time() |> Time.to_string()

MyApp.StoreSchedule
  |> where(
    [rs],
      rs.from_weekday < rs.to_weekday and rs.from_weekday <= ^current_weekday and
      rs.to_weekday >= ^current_weekday and
      ((rs.open_time < rs.close_time and rs.open_time <= ^current_time and
          rs.close_time >= ^current_time) or
         (rs.close_time < rs.open_time and rs.open_time <= ^current_time and
            fragment("'23:59:59' >= ?", ^current_time_string)))
  )
  |> having([rs], count(rs.id) > 0)
  |> group_by([rs], rs.store_id)
  |> select([rs], %{store_id: rs.store_id, count: count(rs.id)})
```

This works fine, but I was thinking if there was some way to remove the `fragment/2` part. I've tried several ways, without success.

**Example 1:**

```
and '23:59:59' >= ^current_time
```

gives error:

```
value `~T[18:35:14]` in `where` cannot be cast to type {:array, :integer} in query:
```

**Example 2:**

```
and ^~T[23:59:59] >= ^current_time
```

gives error:

```
** (ArgumentError) Postgrex expected a binary, got {23, 59, 59, 0}. Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert the value accordingly.
```

Comment: Try `and type(^~T[23:59:59], :time) >= ^current_time`?

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks that worked. I use `type/2` with Timex, but didn't think that with `:time` could also work, I assumed that with :time I didn't need `type/2`